# Large Schematic Dataset

Tags: pcb, schematics, eaglecad, kicad, open-hardware

I am an artist looking to experiment with generating schematics with various machine learning techniques and am looking for a large (ideally 10,000+) publicly available dataset of schematic files. The techniques that I am looking to employ requires that these files be `.sch` (or similar file format that can be opened with KiCad or EAGLE. **Are there more common or interoperable schematic file formats that I should be looking for?**) and not simply images of schematics.

A bit of Googling around led to rather unsatisfactory results and I am not actually much of a hardware guy myself (I've got a basic understanding of circuitry but thats about it). The exact purpose/content of dataset is relatively unimportant provided there are enough files in a format that I can use. For instance, if NASA were to have a database of schematics from certain missions that would suffice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this anything to do with electronic circuitry?

Comment: How do you mean exactly? I realize it isn't a typical post for this stack but this seemed like the type of community that might have the knowledge to answer the question. Such a dataset would also likely be of use to folks learning electrical engineering or using KiCad or EAGLE.

Comment: filetype:sch schematic eagle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On sites like GitHub, circuit schematics are publicly available for download in the number of many thousands.

There are search engines like https://aisler.net/, but it's not easy to use them for batch downloading.

Comment: I was able to search GitHub for "endComp" (to find only `.sch` files that actually include components) and filter so that only language "KiCad" results would be shown. This yielded ~27K results, perfect for my needs. Now just need to write a script that batch downloads them. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could not expect that an intelectual property like a circuit schematic is publicly available for download in such numbers of many thousands.